# Power Shell copy value of one column into a column in another list

Tags: sharepoint-2013, powershell-3.0

I need to copy the values in column 1 in list A into column 3 in list B. I can get scripts to copy the values from column 1 in list A into column 3 in list A but I need to copy to list B...

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$SourceWeb = Get-SPWeb http://mywebsite.com
$SourceList = $SourceWeb.Lists["MyList"]
$DestWeb = Get-SPWeb http://mywebsite2.com
$DestList = $DestWeb.Lists["MyList2"]
foreach ($SourceItem in $SourceList.items)
{
    $DestItem = $destItem.items | ?{$_.ID -eq $SourceItem.ID}
    if ($DestItem -ne $NULL)    
    {
        $DestItem.SystemUpdate() 
    }
 }
```

The code runs and processes but does not update...

Comment: Post what you've got

Comment: Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Comment: This is a site to debug code, not write it. At the very least edit your answer to include copying from column 1 list A to column 3 list A

Comment: Okay let's go back to your first request!! "POST WHAT YOU"VE GOT!" See shortly after what I posted! I did and now you want to do what?? I think I am pretty clear with what I am asking. Don't need code written just need to know where and what I am dong wrong! I don't have time to jack around with this thing... I posted the code you asked for so if you can help then fine I would appreciate it very much but if not go away!

Comment: At the time I posted that comment you had not updated your answer, so I couldn't see what you were doing let alone what you were doing wrong. Calm down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've attempted to iterate through `$destItem` to find the item to update, should be $DestList I think:

```
$DestItem = $DestList.items | ?{$_.ID -eq $SourceItem.ID}
```

The problem is that because $DestItem was $null at this point there was nothing to loop through, thus $DestItem was left at $null and never entered your IF statement.

Comment: Sorry for the delay... you are right and it seems that if the destination column is null then the iteration does not happen to load the items from the other list but if I take items from within the list itself it works. Since I am duplicating the lists completely then I can transfer the items from the ID column to the HISID column within the list.